# python xlrd package gives ValueError when reading a sheet with more than 999999 rows

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, valueerror

I try to read an excel sheet with more than 999999 rows with python `xlrd` module. It gives the following error when reading the row after 999999th row:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 549, in do_row
    self.rowx = int(row_number) - 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1e6'
```

Do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: This looks like a bug in `xlrd`. it looks like Excel provided something like `1e6` for a row number and `int('1e6')` doesn't work. Open an issue [here](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/new). Or change line 549 to something like `self.rowx = int(float(row_number)) - 1`.

Comment: Also, double check to make sure that this hasn't already been solved and that you're using the latest version of `xlrd`.